# Narrowing two consecutive trees in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, narrowing

It is well known that one can narrow a subtree with <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>.

Is it possible to narrow two consecutive trees? How?

Comment: One could certainly build a function or macro to do that, based on `narrow-to-region`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have org speed commands setup, you can put your cursor at the beginning of a headline, press C-spc to start a mark, then press n to select subsequent headlines, and then C-x nn to narrow to the region.

You can do the same without speed commands, just use `C-c C-n` or `C-c C-f` to move to the next headline after setting mark. You can also give these commands a prefix argument, e.g. `C-4 C-c C-n` if you wanted to mark the next 4 headlines.

Comment: `org-mark-element` (bound to `M-h` by default) can select entire elements (for instance headlines.) This command might be useful if someone doesn't have anything set up to navigate org documents quickly.

Comment: True, but to select multiple headlines you would have to type M-h C-x C-x to swap point and mark so you can keep moving the point down to following headlines. Or you have to mark the bottom one with M-h and then move the point up.

Comment: @JohnKitchin Hmm, I can just hit M-h repeatedly to mark many headlines (subtrees) in a row, then narrow. Might be that I have transient-mark-mode on and you do not, though.

Comment: you are right! Interestingly point stays at the top. I had tried it on a large heading that went off screen so I didn't notice that.